# Square Connect API for purchaser

Tags: api, payment, square, square-connect

I'd like to know if it's possible to do some sort of API integration with SQUARE  where I can find my own personal payments done. I'm not a merchant / business owner. This is strictly for personal use for me to play around with the existing API's.

For example, if I made a payment with my credit card at "Joe's Pizzeria" and "Joe's Pizzeria" uses SQUARE for Credit Card payments, can I somehow use SQUARE API to view my personal purchases? 
The purchase should have my name, credit card information, date of purchase, value of purchase and my email.

Any help appreciated. 
Thank you in advance for any answers.

**JB**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to do what you want with the Square API. The API is merchant-focused only. Square does not expose a user's transaction history across multiple merchants in any way.

Comment: Thanks Troy. By any chance are you aware of any payment provider other than Square that's not so merchant-focused?

Comment: Apologies for the slow response to this. This is somewhat OT for stack overflow, but I'm not aware of something exactly like what you're looking for. The issue would be that any payment processor will only have a listing of your transactions that were performed using that processor (i.e. Square will only have purchases you made from Square merchants.) That said, your issuing bank should have all this data, and there are APIs like [Plaid](https://plaid.com/) that you can use to pull it out.